# How to create a sequence of numbers in a Ruby on Rails form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 10 form fields and I want to append a number next to each field, going sequentially from 1 to 10. The problem is that the code is already in a loop. It's inside a partial, and the partial is passed a collection.

```
<%= fields_for "list", f do |f| %>
    <!-- I want 1, 2, etc to appear here depending on the iteration. -->
    <%= f.label :name %>
```

I tried using `<%= i += 1 %>` but it does not work since `i` is not defined. If I define `i`, it will keep getting reset to the same number, so it makes no difference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails automatically defines a local variable called `partialname_counter` where, obviously, "`partialname`" is the name of your partial. So if your partial is called e.g. `_list_item.html.erb` you could write it like this:

```ruby
<%= fields_for "list", f do |f| %>
  <%= list_item_counter + 1 %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
<% end %>
```

(The `+ 1`, of course, is there because the counter starts at `0`.)

**Another option** would be to just let the browser do the numbering for you using an ordered list:

In the view:

```ruby
<ol>
  <%= render :list_item, :collection => @some_items %>
</ol>
```

...and in the partial:

```ruby
<%= fields_for "list", f do |f| %>
  <li>
    <%= f.label :name %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

This option is probably more semantic, and lists are easy to style in CSS.